# Detecting changes in webpage data without refreshing page

Tags: javascript

I'm a complete beginner to javascript. I receive offers of paid UX test via the URL https://app.usertesting.com/my_dashboard/available_tests_v3, but I sometimes miss tests because they can disappear within seconds, so I'm using javascript to play a sound and send a notification when a test appears.

Currently I'm doing this by using javascript to reload() the page every six seconds and checking for the text that matches regex /"device_required"[^,]*/ig.

This works but has a few issues:

1. Reloading the page takes a few seconds, so, along with the CPU usage involved, I can't afford to check every second, which I'd like to do.
2. I have to stop reloading the page once a test appears, else I can't interact with the test. Sometimes I then forget to restart the script by manually refreshing the page.

To fix the above, I'm trying to check the document body for the regex match using setInterval(): without reloading the page first. The problem is this:  Despite the page source immediately changing when tests appear (so the regex should match), and then immediately changing again when tests disappear (so the regex should no longer match), the javascript match() method doesn't "see" the change until the page is refreshed. When a test appears, so the page source now matches the regex, the match(); method still returns null until the page is refreshed.

Here some test code I've created to try to get this working:

```
setInterval(function(){
    'use strict';

    var strDeviceList
    strDeviceList = document.body.innerHTML.match(/"device_required"[^,]*/ig);
    if (strDeviceList) {
        // regex matches, so give a double beep
        beep();
        setTimeout(beep,300);
    } else {
        // regex doesn't match, so give a single beep
        beep();
    }  },1000);
```

This works, except I keep getting a single beep, even after a test appears. I only get the double beep after I refresh the page (either manually or by using reload() in javascript). Note - I'm using match() because I also want to use the text found by the regex.

Here is a snippet from the page source. When there are no tests displayed on the page, the "data: []" is not populated. When there are tests displayed, it is populated, including text that matches the regex.

```
      var sessionsIndex = new App.Views.TesterDashboardAvailableSessionsIndex({
    alert_message_text: {
      hide_tests: {
        heading: "Hide Selected Tests",
        body: "Are you sure you want to hide the selected tests?"
      },
      decline_tests: {
        heading: "Decline Selected Tests",
        body: "Are you sure you want to decline the selected tests?"
      }
    },
    data: []
  });   sessionsIndex.render();
```

Any suggestions?

By the way, instead of a beep, I initially sent text to console.log - but for some reason the text doesn't appear in the console until the page is refreshed. I wonder why this is?

Comment: Can't seem to get "setInterval(function(){" and " }); sessionsIndex.render();" to appear in the grey code box. I pressed Ctrl- K and pasted it in. How do i fix this?

Comment: Please add any questions and code as edits to your question - not as a comment - these tend top get lost if back and forth goes on losing context

Comment: The question in comments is about editing the post to display correctly, not about my code / javascript. But it seems someone has fixed this for me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it was never going to work like this, because the page needs to be refreshed to get the latest details - and looking at the page source itself must be retrieving the latest details from the server.

So I came up with a better way using XMLHttpRequest(). (I tried to use fetch() but couldn't seem to get it work in Chrome / Tampermonkey).

```
setInterval(function(){
'use strict';

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var strHTML
var strDeviceList

xhr.open("GET","https://app.usertesting.com/my_dashboard/available_tests_v3");
xhr.send();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 /* DONE */) {
        strHTML = xhr.responseText;
        strDeviceList = strHTML.match(/"device_required"[^,]*/ig);
        if (strDeviceList) {
            // regex matches, so give a double beep
            beep();
            setTimeout(beep,300);
        } else {
            // regex doesn't match, so give a single beep
            beep();
      }
    }
} 
},1000);
```

This has much improved the response times for alerting me to changes, and reduced CPU usage from up to 60% to less than 9%. I suppose the code could be improved though, at least in style?